# Running a model several times with BehaviorSpace

Tags: netlogo

From BehaviorSpace, I would like to run a model 100 times by varying two variables as follows:

```
["x-area" 1 ] and ["y-area" [1 1 100]].
```

A model is built as follows:

- create landscape
- add-turtles
- go-simulation

By using the two variables, I would like that my 100 models run as follows:

```
;;; Model 1 ;;
"x-area" = 1
"y-area" = 1
clear-all
create landscape
add-turtles
go-simulation

;;; Model 2 ;;
"x-area" = 1
"y-area" = 2
add-turtles
go-simulation

;;; Model 3 ;;
"x-area" = 1
"y-area" = 3
add-turtles
go-simulation

 ....

;;; Model 100 ;;
"x-area" = 1
"y-area" = 100
add-turtles
go-simulation
```

To do this, I built 100 experiments and this method worked. Is there a faster way to run automatically 100 models without doing 100 experiments ? I tried to build 1 experiment like this

[image]

But I have this error message:

OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead.

```
 org.nlogo.nvm.ArgumentTypeException: OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset  or turtle or patch but got NOBODY instead.
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduremovewithinpolygon_ifelse_86.perform(:4)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusive(Context.java:119)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run(ExclusiveJob.java:57)
at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Context.java:162)
at org.nlogo.prim._asm_procedurestartsimulation_ask_69.perform(:1)
at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)
at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)
```

The problem is that my models continue to run with this error. So it is difficult to see where is the problem. Given the following message:

```
"at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduremovewithinpolygon_ifelse_86.perform(:4)" in the error message,
```

maybe that the problem is in the procedure "move-within-polygon".

Here is my procedure "move-within-polygon" for a given color of polygons:

```
 if [pcolor] of patch-here = green [

  set list-angles-in-green item 0 table-angles

loop [

  let angle-in-green one-of list-angles-in-green 

  ifelse [pxcor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pxcor or [pycor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pycor [
      print "die"
      die
      stop ]

  [ ifelse (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) != nobody and [pcolor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = green [
    print "move"
    move-to patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1

  [ if not any? neighbors with [pcolor = green] [
      print "no neighbors"
      move-to patch-here
      stop ] ] ] ] ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Clarifying one of Seth Tisue's comments, when you get that error message, doesn't NetLogo highlight the code that's generating the error?  If the program continues to run, it might be hard to see which line it is, but you should be able to figure out where the problem is occurring.

Comment: By the way, is `go-simulation` only supposed to run once?  If you put it in the "go" column, it will run multiple times.  That wouldn't have anything to do with the error, though.

Comment: Thanks very much Mars. `add-turtles` and `go-simulation` are supposed to run for each model i.e., for `Model 1 with x-area = 1 and y-area = 1`, for `the Model 2 with x-area = 1 and y-area = 2`, .... for `the model 100 with x-area = 1 and y-area = 100.`

Comment: If a turtle ends up on the edge of the world, then `patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1` might point outside the world (depending on what `angle-in-green` is), so `[pxcor] of` in `[pxcor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pxcor` would ask for the coordinate of `nobody`.  The same thing could happen for `pycor` later in the same line.  Can a turtle ever get to the edge of the world?  It looks to me like the code that you displayed could lead to that result.

Comment: Thanks very much Mars. I think you are right ! But How can I specify that if a turtle is outside the world at the edges around max-pxcor and max-pycor (and not min-pxcor and min-pYcor), the turtle dies ? Thanks very much.

Comment: A turtle can't get outside the world (unless you set the world to wrap, but then "going outside" means coming in the other side).  I'll post an answer, copying my previous remark, based on the assumption that this is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a turtle ends up on the edge of the world, then `patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1` might point outside the world (depending on what `angle-in-green` is), so `[pxcor] of` in `[pxcor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pxcor` would ask for the coordinate of `nobody`. The same thing could happen for `pycor` later in the same line.

Question: Can a turtle ever get to the edge of the world in your model? It looks to me like the code that you displayed could lead to that result.

If so, then one way to prevent the error would be to replace

```
[pxcor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pxcor
```

with

```
xcor = max-pxcor
```

That's true when a turtle reaches the last column of patches.  If you also want turtles to die when they're close to the edge, you could use both of these expressions in the `if-else`:

```
(xcor = max-pxcor) or ([pxcor] of (patch-right-and-ahead angle-in-green 1) = max-pxcor)
```

(I added parentheses simply for clarity.)

However, I wonder whether this would serve the same purpose:

```
xcor = max-pxcor or xcor = max-pxcor - 1
```

If any of these methods are right for your application, then you can obviously do the same thing for the y coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Your experiment setup appears correct to me, except that you should remove the "Stop condition" of `TRUE`, because if the stop condition is always true, your runs will never run the go commands even once.

The error you're getting is coming from code that you haven't shown us, so I can't help you there. You'll need to show us the code in which the error is occurring.

Also, at the time the error occurs, what are the values of `x-area` and `y-area`? And does the same error occur if you set `x-area` and `y-area` to the same values outside BehaviorSpace? If so, then the error doesn't really have anything to do with BehaviorSpace.

Finally, a note on terminology: there is only one model here, not 100, and only one experiment here, not 100. You're attempting to run one experiment on your model, and that experiment consists of 100 model runs. Using the standard terminology will help you communicate your issue clearly.

Comment: Thanks very much Seth for your answer. I noted several problems with my experiment setup above:1) the run begins directly to #2 of 100 (instead of #1 of 100), 2) the values of x-zone and y-zone don't increase at each iteration (I have always x-zone = 0 and y-zone = 1 when my model is running), 3) I don't have the error outside BehaviorSpace, and 4) when the error occurs, the model continues to run. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: 1) Your stop condition of `true` would account for that. Did you fix that yet? If so, you should update the question. 2) Your experiment varies `x-area` and `y-area`, not `x-zone` and `y-zone`. Is there something in your code that varies the latter based on the values of the former? If so, maybe the problem is in that code. 3) How hard have you tried to reproduce the error outside BehaviorSpace? It's highly implausible, though not impossible, that there is some BehaviorSpace-specific issue here.

Comment: Thanks very much Seth. 1) When I delete "TRUE" in "Stop condition", I have always the same problem: the values of x-area and y-area don't increase at each iteration. 2) There are only two variables that vary: x-area and y-area (sorry, there are no x-zone and y-zone. It's a mistake on the part of me) 3) When I run one experiment with, for example, x-area = 1 and y-area = 1 (i.e, by running one model instead of 100) and when I don't use BehaviorSpace, I don't have this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I added other information about the error message in my question.

Comment: It's only `y-area` that you want to change from run to run, right?  `x-area` should always be = 1.

Comment: I hadn't noticed before that your go commands were blank. If the entire run happens in your setup commands, then it actually makes sense to use a stop condition of `true`, because you always want the run to stop immediately once the setup commands are complete. Normally, though, I would put `go-simulation` in under go commands, and use a time limit of 1 to stop the simulation.